# Use Nashorn but not javax.script

Tags: java, nashorn

I have a project to complete and I can't use javax.script, so can I use Nashorn but not use javax.script?

Comment: not so clear question , could you elaborate a bit more ? are u using the latest java version ? have you imported the JDK or the JRE to your IDE? what do you mean use Nashorn but not use javax.script ? Have you read a simple tutorial like [this](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/)

Comment: Of course you can use Nashorn. Use jjs from the command line. Otherwise, use javax.script.ScriptEngine from code. I'd be curious to know why you think you can't use javax.script. It's part of the Java runtime, same as another class in Java 8. Possible [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "jjs" command line tool in jdk/bin to evaluate scripts. That tool can evaluate scripts from files/urls or can also work in interactive mode. The tool does not use javax.script API - but uses Nashorn directly

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nashorn API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/index.html) directly, e.g. you can start from the `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory` class, but a lot of the API implicitly relies on the `javax.script` package later on. I'm not sure why you have the limitation, though; `javax.script` is a standard JDK package, it's in every Java runtime since around Java 1.5 or 6.

That said, direct API usage allows you to get customized `ScriptEngine`s, because `NashornScriptEngineFactory` has some overloads for the `getScriptEngine()` method that allow you to pass `jjs` command line arguments, a custom class loader to use by the engine, and so on.

Another minor thing that using Nashorn API directly buys you is that you will know that you're definitely getting a Nashorn engine, something you couldn't necessarily be certain if you just asked for a JS engine from `javax.script`.